# How to Display two table in mysql together without joining

Tags: mysql

Hello anyone can tell me what should I study about joining a table if I want to display two table with same row name? its hard to explain but I can give an example

I have 2 tables name tbwinner and tbloser.
they have the same rows ( ID, Date, Name, Points, Result )

what I want is to display all tbwinner rows with specific Date together with the tbloser asc by ID.

example

```
ID, Date, Name, Points, Result
1, 12-12-2001, Tester1, 50, Lose (this is from table tbloser)
2, 12-12-2001, Tester2, 90, Win  (this is from table tbwinner)
3, 12-12-2001, Tester3, 87, Win  (this is from table tbwinner)
1, 12-12-2001, Tester4, 40, Lose (this is from table tbloser)
```

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM tbwinner
INNER JOIN tbloser ON tbwinner.Date = tbloser.PVDate where tblpvdeleted.PVDate ='2023-01-09' OR tblpv.PVDate = '2023-01-09'
```

The result show is for tbwinner only and the loser table is not displaying.

the result is half good, because only the tbwinner is display while the tbloser is not

I hope someone can understand this thanks

Comment: 'anyone can tell me what should I study about joining a table ' - UNION https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use either approach as per your need:

**Using UNION**

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM table2
)
WHERE < your condition >
```

**Multi-select (easy)**

```
SELECT * from table1,table2
```

Comment: 'INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: Thank you so much I use the union and its work